# How can I remove the covers of my shower’s handle to tighten the screws?

Tags: doors, shower, screws, cover

The handle of the door of my shower is a bit loose.

[image: Loose showe]

I think it is possible to tighten the screws, but they seem hidden by a cover, which I have not been able to remove using my fingers alone.

[image: Screws hidden by a cover]

Is there a way to temporarily remove these covers, without damaging them?

Comment: Check the inside of the door first.  They are probably quite tight and will need something thin metal to ply off.  Work the bottom and remember skin does not like thin metal.

Comment: those are terrible quality pictures (to dark) but normally those are snap on (or twist lock), for safety reason you have to work on the inside to access

Comment: Sorry about the picture quality, I tried making better ones but they still look as dark. Thanks for your reply, I was able to remove (then put back) the covers. If you think the community will benefit from an anwser I will post it with the pictures.

Comment: Questioners are encouraged to answer their own questions.

Comment: turn off the flash on the camera and turn on room lights and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to your comments, I was able to remove the covers using a flat screwdriver.

[image: Removing the covers with a flat screwdriver]

It can be useful to drive different angles of attack. In my case, I think the screwdriver was not thin enough and I had to use my nails to be able to squeeze the screwdriver between the cover and the rest of the handle.

Once removed, the covers looked like this:

[image: Removed covers]

Again, sorry for the picture quality, I was not able to take better ones.

It was then straightforward to tighten the screws of the handle:

[image: The screw is now visible]

When replacing the covers, it may be best to orient their pins in a specific way, so that it’s easier to know where to put the screwdriver next time they are to be removed.